# How to automatically show Facebook page posts, twitter feed and instagram on website

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, web, instagram

I have a website, and I also have Facebook page, twitter account and Instagram for pictures. Instead of people going to three sites, I want to create a page in my website, so that everything is in one place.

So for example, I made a post on Facebook, so in my website, the post is shown there, and then if I tweeted something, then it automatically shows up in my website in a chronological order.

I don't want to keep embedding it every time I make a post.

Thanks

Comment: [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines)
 
[Instagram API](http://instagram.com/developer)
 
[Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/products/sharing/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically there are two possibilities.

If you only have some basic knowledge of HTML, you can embed feeds/timelines in your website:
Twitter: https://blog.twitter.com/2012/embedded-timelines-howto
Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin (only for Pages)
Instagram: http://snapwidget.com/ (third party)

Alternatively you have a lot more freedom by using the public API's of those sites, but it's a lot harder to implement.